# Symfony 2, how to redirect form response to a new window

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form that generates a pdf document that will be served to the user when submitted.  I would like to have the pdf document open in a new window.  How would I do that using Symfony forms?  I've been doing some Google searching but have not been able to find any ready answers to how to do this.

I found the answer to my question and added it as reference for other Symfony developers. See my response below to learn how to use it in your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get your form to redirect to a new window is insanely simple, once you know how.  When you create your form ( if you are using form classes, which you should ), your form creation will look something like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormName(), $myObject);
```

To add the ability for your form to redirect, you need to add the third argument to your constructor, like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    new MyFormName(),
    $myObject,
    array( 
        'attr' => array( 
            'target' => '_blank' 
        )
    )
);
```

Now, when your form is submitted, it opens the results in a new window.

I hope this information helps other developers from hitting their heads on their keyboards like I was doing.